# How to proceed with this Maasai translation?

Tags: computational-linguistics, linguistic-typology, theoretical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics

---

The problem statement is as follows:

[image: Problem Statement]

**Question:**  Indicate which translation goes with each Maasai sentence.

---

**My current approach:**

1. The word {word1}  [image: Maasai word] appears a total of 8 times in the Maasai sentences given and the word *warrior* appears 8 times in the given English sentences. So {word1} matches to *warrior*.
2. The word {word2} [image: Maasai word] and the word {word3} [image: Maasai word] appears a total of 3 times. Since {word1} matched to a noun, I assume {word2} and {word3} also would match to nouns and thus can correspond to *snake* and *tree*.
3. Sentences (2) and (7) do not contain the word {word1}. Similarly, sentences (H) and (J) do not contain the word *warrior*. So these two pairs must correspond to each other.
4. Proceeding in a similar manner, we can make out that {word2} would correspond to *tree* and {word3} would correspond to *snake*.
5. Now we are left with pronouns and verbs. Proceeding with some assumptions and in a similar manner as above, we might get some results, but that involves **a lot** of assumptions.

---

After this, I am not able to proceed forwards, maybe because I am not being able to categorize the pronouns in *first person*, *second person*, and/or *third person*. Also, the verbs and pronouns in some sentences seem to be mixed in one(To me, the Maasai language appears to have the concept of *Sandhi* like in *Sanskrit*, or maybe has the concept of affixes of morphemes, like in English).

---

Please tell me if I stumped somewhere and guide me how to proceed forward. Also, I am not able to find the answer key to this problem, so I cannot verify any solutions. Providing the same would be helpful.

---

**P.S.** Sorry for the inconvenience caused by using {word1}, {word2} etc. I could not post more than 8 image links here.

---

Comment: I would love to help you out, (iol participant from India), but seeing the stack exchange rules, it would be better that you asked this at chat

Comment: @WiccanKarnak How do I message you? I am new to stack exchange. :)

Comment: I have created a room called "Linguistics puzzle" , search for it and join

Comment: Well then let's discuss here, the steps you mentioned... is it the ones you took, or you saw it written down somewhere?

Comment: No, these are the steps I took.

Comment: So ok, for any problem like this it's really difficult to think like the original solver, so you will have to tell me which assumption exactly are you facing problem with.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! As per the image links, you can upload the images normally and either (1) paste links in comment or (2) commit an edit to your question, *removing some existing* image links and adding the new ones. The images reside on Imgur permanently, and your edits are stored in edit history. So a high-reputation user can edit the post from both revisions and make all images available at the same time.

Comment: If you google "the warrior cuts me" including the quotes you will get more data.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak Looks like I figured it out. Please check the answer section.

Comment: Will go through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I solved it myself.

---

My first assumption, as mentioned in the question itself, is correct. Thus, [image: Maasai word] corresponds to *warrior*.

In my second assumption, there can be two cases:

---

**Case I:**

[image: Maasai word] **corresponds to** *tree* **and** [image: Maasai word] **corresponds to** *snake*.

---

Proceeding on to my point 3 in the question with this assumption, we find that [image: Maasai prefix] prefix would correspond to *I* and [image: Maasai prefix] prefix would correspond to *me*.

Similarly, [image: Maasai verb] would correspond to *cut* and [image: Maasai verb] to *sees(s)*.

However, if we move on with the current assumption-based results, and try to decipher sentence 9, we would get an English translation with the keywords: *Warrior*, *sees*, *I*, which could meaningfully translate to *I see the warrior*, or unmeaningfully translate to *The warrior sees I*.

The second translation would be gramatically incorrect and we do not find the first translation in the English sentences given. Therefore, our assumption was wrong.

---

**Case II:**

[image: Maasai word] **corresponds to** *snake* **and** [image: Maasai word] **corresponds to** *tree*.

---

Proceeding in the same method as CASE I, we find the following results:

[image: Maasai prefix]   -->> *me*
[image: Maasai prefix]   -->> *I*
[image: Maasai verb]     -->> *see(s)*
[image: Maasai verb]     -->> *cut*

Note that these results give a suitable translation for sentence 9, which is, *The warrior cuts me*.

Now that we have these results, the problem becomes fairly easy to solve.

The results would be:

[image: Maasai Answers]